# How do I store the date in a variable correctly using getdate()

Tags: php

I am attempting to store the date in a variable using getdate().  What am I doing wrong?

```
$today = getdate();

echo "the date today is ".$today;
```

Output: the date today is Array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[getdate()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php) returns an array so you might want to do something like

```
echo 'The date today is '. $today['year'].'-'.$today['mon'].'-'.$today['mday'];
```

I would prefer using [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
echo 'The date today is '. date('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

`getdate()` returns an array. To echo seconds, you might want to try this:

```
$getdate = getdate();

echo "there are ".$getdate['seconds']." on the minute";
```

Check out all the keys and what they return [here.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php)

Answer (score 0):

That's because  getdate() returns an array. Try

```
print_r($today)
```

to see for yourself. Also [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php) should help you.